# Android CALL_PHONE runtime permission

Tags: java, android, runtime

i have method for get runtime permission i searched for that long but still have no answer can anyone help me to modify my code ? cause its never show request dialog for get user permission after user accept permission move to next activity 
here my code that i made but some how its never made a request

```
public class perm extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING = 200;
private View view;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dash);
    isPermissionGranted();

}

public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(permissions.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
    if(grantResults.length>0){
        for(int grantResult: grantResults){
            if(grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                allPermissionsGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!allPermissionsGranted){
        boolean somePermissionsForeverDenied = false;
        for(String permission: permissions){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)){
                //denied
                Log.e("denied", permission);
            }else{
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //allowed
                    Log.e("allowed", permission);
                } else{
                    //set to never ask again
                    Log.e("set to never ask again", permission);
                    somePermissionsForeverDenied = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(somePermissionsForeverDenied){
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Permissions Required")
                    .setMessage("You have forcefully denied some of the required permissions " +
                            "for this action. Please open settings, go to permissions and allow them.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                    Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    } else {
        switch (requestCode) {
            //act according to the request code used while requesting the permission(s).
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you debug through your code to figure out where it's going wrong?

Comment: yes my device api is 23

Comment: are you declaring the same permission in manifest as well?